# Make JAWS read role columnheader every-time before the column value

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

hope you are doing great. So, for one of my recent projects I need to do something really similar to the page apple built for comparing 
iPad models. (https://www.apple.com/la/ipad/compare/) the web needs to be accessible and, unfortunately, this part has already been built but a11y wasn't really taken into account and now we need to refactor it. So I went through the apple web an saw that their layout is somehow similar to ours. Also,  I tested using NVDA and I think this is what I need. Every time, before reading the column value, NVDA reads the column header that is set to the selected product. That way, the user can know what product has that feature. Then I tested on Jaws and found that it is not reading the headers every time before the value. That is not good because the user is not able to know the product that has the feature being read. Is there a configuration that needs to be activated to have the same behavior from NVDA into JAWS? Jaws is important for the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should make sure you're using `<th>` and maybe `<thead>` correctly.

According to [WebAIM's guide to testing with JAWS](https://webaim.org/articles/jaws/#tables), that reader offers extra shortcuts to read related headers.

> To skip to a table, press the T key. To navigate between cells, hold down Ctrl + Alt and use ↑/↓/←/→ to move from cell to cell. Ctrl + Alt + 5 (on the numeric keypad) will read the row and/or column headers for the current cell.

This behaviour is the product designers' decision, so you shouldn't try to overwrite it.

I would also recommend involving actual screen reader users in your testing.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your answer and recommendation. So, you are saying that the only way to achieve what I want on JAWS is by using the commands you listed before? Thanks

Comment: It's probably configurable in JAWS, the important thing is that JAWS users will be accustomed to that behaviour. It's not an issue the author needs to fix.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using native HTML, then your job is much easier.  If you are cobbling a table together using <div> and <span> tags, you have a bit more work but it can be done.

So for a simple table like on the Apple website, you'd have something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    <th scope="col">iPad Pro</th>
    <th scope="col">iPad Air</th>
    <th scope="col">iPad</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Height</th>
    <td>11.04 inches</td>
    <td>9.8 inches</td>
    <td>9.4 inches</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Width</th>
    <td>8.46 inches</td>
    <td>6.8 inches</td>
    <td>6.6 inches</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Note, you could put the <th scope="col"> in a <thead>, and the main <tr>s in a <tbody>, but I'm keeping this simple.

Using native HTML, your job is done.  The table has **both** column and row headers.  When you navigate using a screen reader going across a row, the column header will be announced before the cell value.  If you navigate down a column, the row header will be announced before the cell value.

If you are not using table elements but rather <div>s and <span>s, you'd have to specify [`roles`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) for all the elements (and have CSS to appropriately lay out the table).  It'd be something like:

```html
<div role="table">
  <div role="row">
    <div role="columnheader"></div>
    <div role="columnheader">iPad Pro</div>
    <div role="columnheader">iPad Air</div>
    <div role="columnheader">iPad</div>
  </div>
  <div role="row">
    <div role="rowheader">Height</div>
    <div role="cell">11.04 inches</div>
    <div role="cell">9.8 inches</div>
    <div role="cell">9.4 inches</div>
  </div>
  <div role="row">
    <div role="rowheader">Width</div>
    <div role="cell">8.46 inches</div>
    <div role="cell">6.8 inches</div>
    <div role="cell">6.6 inches</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't have to do anything special in the screen reader to hear the row and column headers if you're using the screen reader with its default settings.  JAWS, NVDA, and VoiceOver should all honor them.

Comment: Hi slugolicious, thanks for the answer. Yeah, because of how the page was built I have to do something similar to your second example. Have you tried jaws with the apple page? I have done it but I don't hear the column header before the value every time.  Only once. Unless I try the approach that Andy described before.

Comment: I don't have a JAWS license so can't try it, but when I did have a license, navigating through a table worked just fine.  Even the "faked out" aria table worked in JAWS.  The column headers were read before the data cell.  I didn't see a solution in @andy's post.  He just mentioned how you navigate through a table using the screen reader keys.